# how to test django project

Tags: python, django

I wrote some test case to test my django project, when I run them in jenkins it always create a **default database**, I want to test my project with my own database, how to do?

Comment: Austin Phillips's answer is a good idea, but it is really use your own database?
I have test it, it just create a database name as "TEST_NAME".

Comment: I just want to tell you, if you need to test it before accept an answer

Comment: I did it will, it works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django always expects to have a **default** database as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) for the DATABASES setting.

The **default** tags is simply the name by which you refer to the database, not the name of the database itself.  In the documentation example above, even though the database handle is **default**, the name of the database itself is **mydatabase**.

When you're testing, it is usual to use a different database than your production database and for this you can use the TEST_NAME specification for the database.  The following settings.py shows the names of the databases used during production and unit testing.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST_NAME': 'mytestdatabase'
    }
}
```

The following link gives some useful information on testing.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/